# Binding to nested dependency properties of custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have several custom controls derived from DockPanel, ToggleButton, ComboBox, etc. I have a class `Props` that I want to use as a dependency property in each of those derived classes. All of those classes need to have the same dependency properties (contained in `Props`) and maybe several of unique properties of their own (e.g. only in Dock Panel). 
An example use case are properties ExistsInConfig and RightVisible. I want the control to only be visible when both are set to true. This logic should be available in all my custom derived controls.

DockPanel.cs:

```
public class DockPanel : System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel
{
    public DockPanel()
    {
        Props = new Props();
    }

    public Props Props
    {
        get
        {
            return (Props)GetValue(Properties);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Properties, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Properties =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Props", typeof(Props), typeof(DockPanel), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Props.cs:

```
public class Props: DependencyObject
{
    public Props(){}

    public bool RightVisible { get; set;}

    public bool ExistsInConfig { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RightVisibleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RightVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(Props), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExistsInConfigProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ExistsInConfig", typeof(bool), typeof(Props), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static bool GetExistsInConfig(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ExistsInConfigProperty);
    }

    public static void SetExistsInConfig(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
       obj.SetValue(ExistsInConfigProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetRightVisible(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(RightVisibleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRightVisible(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RightVisibleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Style for DockPanel:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomDockPanelStyle" TargetType="custom:DockPanel">
    <Setter Property="Visibility">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultipleBooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Props.ExistsInConfig" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Props.RightVisible" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Using the control in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type custom:DockPanel}" BasedOn={StaticResource CustomDockPanelStyle}"
</Window.Resources>

<custom:DockPanel 
custom:Props.ExistsInConfig="{Binding ElementName=ToggleCombinedVisibility, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
custom:Props.RightVisible="{Binding ElementName=ToggleCombinedVisibility, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleCombinedVisibility" IsChecked="True" />
```

The problem is, the binding doesn't work. The `MultipleBooleanToVisibilityConverter` does only get called on loading the view and not when I try to toggle visibility with a button. If I specify callbacks in PropertyMetadata of `RightVisible` and `ExistsInConfig`, they get called after toggling the button, but the converter doesn't.

Do I have to let DockPanel know that `Props` has changed? How do I go about that? I couldn't figure a way to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` across two classes.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding paths in your `Style` are wrong.

Attached properties should by surrounded by parentheses and custom attached properties should be preceded by a namespace alias.

This should work:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomDockPanelStyle" TargetType="custom:DockPanel">
    <Setter Property="Visibility">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultipleBooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(custom:Props.ExistsInConfig)" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(custom:Props.RightVisible)" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```